# When converting DocBook, pandoc can't find image

Tags: cmake, pandoc, docbook

I'm writing documentation for a program and would like to include a screenshot. The `CMakeLists.txt` file, which is in the `doc` subdirectory, looks like this:

```
find_program(PANDOC pandoc)

if (PANDOC)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT perfecttin.pdf MAIN_DEPENDENCY perfecttin.xml COMMAND pandoc -f docbook -o perfecttin.pdf -V papersize=a4 --data-dir=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/perfecttin.xml)
add_custom_target(perfecttin-doc ALL DEPENDS perfecttin.pdf)
endif ()
```

The section of the DocBook file looks like this:

```
<section id="window">
  <title>Main Window</title>
  <mediaobject>
    <imageobject>
      <imagedata fileref="window1.png" format="PNG"/>
    </imageobject>
  </mediaobject>
</section>
```

`window1.png` is in the same directory as `CMakeLists.txt` and `perfecttin.xml`. I've tried it with and without `--data-dir=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc`, and I get the same error:

```
[pandoc warning] Could not find image `window1.png', skipping...
```

How do I tell pandoc where to look for the image?

Comment: Looks like you need to use `--resource-path=<dir>` parameter: exactly this directory(ies) affects on where images are searched. Parameter `--data-dir=<dir>` is ... for some other purposes. Note, that by default CMake executes custom COMMAND in the current **binary** directory, not in the **source** one where you have `CMakeLists.txt` and other files. But you may change default working directory with `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option.

Comment: @Tsyvarev This gives me an "unrecognized option" error in pandoc 1.19.2.4 (on Ubuntu Bionic). My DragonFly box, however, has pandoc 2.7.2_1. I'll try it there, but will have to detect the version number in CMake.

Comment: It works on 2.7.2. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: I am not an expert in pandoc ("my" tag is CMake, but the core of your problem is not about CMake usage) . The suggestion about using different parameter was based only on [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), I have never tested it. If it works for you, then fell free to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The option to do this is `--resource-path`, but that is not available on the version of pandoc on Ubuntu Bionic. So to build the documentation on a newer version, but not break the entire build on an older version, I added code to check whether pandoc supports the option. Here is the working CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_program(PANDOC pandoc)

if (PANDOC)
execute_process(COMMAND ${PANDOC} "--resource-path=/" INPUT_FILE /dev/null ERROR_FILE /dev/null RESULT_VARIABLE pandoc_exit)
endif ()

if (PANDOC AND NOT pandoc_exit)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT perfecttin.pdf MAIN_DEPENDENCY perfecttin.xml COMMAND pandoc -f docbook -o perfecttin.pdf -V papersize=a4 --resource-path=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/perfecttin.xml)
add_custom_target(perfecttin-doc ALL DEPENDS perfecttin.pdf)
endif ()
```

`if (PANDOC AND NOT pandoc_exit)` sounds backward, but the exit code for success is 0, which CMake takes as false, while the code for error is 2, which it takes as true.